# linux script simple arithmetic code

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, math

So I'm just working on some simple arithmetic code. Here's what I got:

```
echo "The number should be 2";

declare -i input added

input= date +%w

let added="input/2"

echo "$added"
```

when I run it the output is

```
4
0
```

I'm trying to just get 2.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is how you are creating the `input` variable.  It is just executing the command, but not assigning the result to `input`.  Instead, do:

```
input=$(date +%w)
```

This will assign the output of the `date` command to `input`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate way:

```
#Just echo the result:
expr $(date +%w) / 2

#store the result into a variable:
input=$(expr $(date +%w) / 2)

echo $input
2
```

Comment: no need to call external expr. bash can do a bit of arithmetic on its own.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that in Bash you generally can't have spaces around the equal sign.

An alternate syntax to using `let` is to use `$(())` or `(())`:

```
var2=$((var1 / 2))
```

Or

```
((var2 = var1 / 2))
```

Inside the double parentheses, you can use spaces and you can omit the dollar sign from the beginning of variable names.